# WCF Works As Svc Host But Not As Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service that works correctly when hosted in WCFSvcHost; However when I host it as a Windows Service I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll. Additional information: The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.

Below is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FileBetService.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="LargeMessageBinding" 
                  contract="FileBetService.IService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/FB/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeMessageBinding" 
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 closeTimeout="00:15:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:15:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:15:00" 
                 sendTimeout="00:15:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have made some suggested changes to my app config with the error no longer occuring but the metadata (wsdl) is not being displayed

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service name="FileBetService.Service">
<host>
<baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/IService/"/>
</baseAddresses>
</host>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contrac="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/FBTurf12/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeMessageBinding" contract="FileBetService.IService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="default">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:8000/IService/mex"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeMessageBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:15:00" openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Well, you see, the HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address. So, in this case, you either need to supply a http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.  If you do that, you'll get past this error.

Comment: I have a base address http://localhost:8000/FB/ is this incorrect?

Comment: I think the problem is how you've configured it.  Check the answer on this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658455/invalid-operation-exception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Operation Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658455/invalid-operation-exception)